# How to change the location of a swapfile?

Tags: hard-drive, files, ssd, swap

Thanks to [this](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/amp/), I have a swapfile on my primary ssd drive (500GB) where I have Ubuntu installed. I have a faster ssd (2TB). I’d like to move my swapfile to the faster drive if possible, if not how do I correctly go about creating a new swapfile on the faster drive and then deleting the initial swapfile and all related  references/entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new swap file anywhere you like. Then update `/etc/fstab` and add there the new path, also remove the old one.

Then you can reboot and delete the old swap file.

It can be done without rebooting using

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo swapon -a
```

Swap file permissions should be `600`. Format it using `mkswap` command.